# Is css :last-child supported in all browsers?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Does :last-child work in all major browsers?

Comment: Good reference for these questions; http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported in IE 8 and lower but all other modern browsers support it including IE9+, Chrome 2+, Fx 3+, Safari 3.1+ and Opera 9.5+.

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Internet Explorer 7 and 8 are still two of the [most used browsers](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php), and they don't support the `:last-child` pseudoclass.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. Most browsers support it since one or two years, MS IE still lacks support.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild#compatibilitysection

Answer (score 0):

In short it works in all the *latest releases* of the major browsers, but before IE9 it is not supported.